# Writing / Accessing points in a PointCloud2 structure C++ / ROS / PCL Library

Tags: c++, file-io, ros, point-cloud-library, pcl

I am currently building a perception pipeline and am having trouble reading the points of my point cloud structure. I am reading in a point cloud into a PointCloud2 Structure and want to be able to write out the points in series of the point cloud or at the very least access them so I find a way to write them to a file later. The basic code I am working with is here:

```
void cloud_cropbox_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &cloud_msg)
{
    // Container for original & filtered data
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 *cloud = new pcl::PCLPointCloud2;
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr cloudPtr(cloud);
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered;

    // convert given message into PCL data type
    pcl_conversions::toPCL(*cloud_msg, *cloud);
```

I want to be able to access the x,y,z elements of each point in the cloud and ideally just write them all out to a textfile. I have tried using `pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII()` but I don't think that is quite applicable here. An additional note is the base program is constantly running and never exits until manually closed I don't know if that will be relavent to writing out to a file. Any help on what exact functions to use / steps I need to take would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to write out the contents of the message to a file, you can just (in launch file or commandline) use [`ros topic echo [args] > my_file.txt`](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_echo).

For ways that are compatible in C++, I recommend reading from http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros, which describes that:

> pcl_ros extends the ROS C++ client library to support message passing with PCL native data types. Simply add the following include to your ROS node source code:
> `#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>`
> This header allows you to publish and subscribe pcl::PointCloud objects as ROS messages. These appear to ROS as sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages, offering seamless interoperability with non-PCL-using ROS nodes. For example, you may publish a pcl::PointCloud in one of your nodes and visualize it in rviz using a Point Cloud2 display. It works by hooking into the roscpp serialization infrastructure.

This means that you can internally use PCL all you want, and it's all a ROS PointCloud2 message. But you have to declare the PCL type / interface you want to use in the message / publisher / subscriber that you access the data with. So instead of using the `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` type everywhere, use the `pcl::Pointcloud<pcl::Point*>` type everywhere.

[Publishing](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Publishing_point_clouds):

```c++
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);
PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
msg->points.push_back (pcl::PointXYZ(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
pub.publish (msg);
```

[Subscribing](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Subscribing_to_point_clouds):

```c++
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("points2", 1, callback);
void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg){
  printf ("Cloud: width = %d, height = %d\n", msg->width, msg->height);
  BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, msg->points)
  printf ("\t(%f, %f, %f)\n", pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
}
```

More examples (or links to node source code) in http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros, tutorials on other pipeline stuff in http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials.